# CSS sibling selector on class names?

Tags: css, dom, siblings

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="firstChild"></div>
  <div class="secondChild"></div>
  <div class="thirdChild"></div>
  <div class="fourthChild"></div>
<div>
```

I am trying to style fourthChildbased on if secondChild exists under parent

I thought the below would work but Chrome says no. I dont want to use nth child because the DOM could change based on our program, the below seems very flexible but I'm doing something wrong.

```
.parent .secondchild ~ .fourthchild
{
     css stuff
}
```

Comment: turns out the magic selector was

    .parent div.secondChild ~ div.fourthChild"

Answer (score 9):

It's the correct solution, you just wrongly named your classes in the CSS, you forgot the caps.

```
.parent .secondChild ~ .fourthChild
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LeBen/Y6QDr/

Comment: I agree LeBen, I do the same for HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 3):

It's case sensitive!
Do this:

```
.parent .secondChild ~ .fourthChild
```

Comment: ups... late! :) @LeBen